# Why is my array not being filled in this python script?

Tags: python, binary, binaryfiles

I have a pyramid/python application with the following view callable:

```
@view_config(route_name='home_page', renderer='templates/edit.pt')
def home_page(request):
    if 'form.submitted' in request.params:
        name= request.params['name']

        input_file=request.POST['stl'].file
        vertices, normals = [],[]
        if input_file.read(5) == b'solid':
            for line in input_file:
                parts = line.split()
                if parts[0] == 'vertex':
                    vertices.append(map(float, parts[1:4]))
                elif parts[0] == 'facet':
                    normals.append(map(float, parts[2:5]))

            ordering=[]
            N=len(normals)
            for i in range(0,N):
                ordering.append([3*i,3*i+1,3*i+2])
            data=[vertices,ordering]
        else:
            f=input_file
            points=[]
            triangles=[]
            normals=[]
            def unpack (f, sig, l):
                s = f.read (l)
                fb.append(s)
                return struct.unpack(sig, s)

            def read_triangle(f):
                n = unpack(f,"<3f", 12)
                p1 = unpack(f,"<3f", 12)
                p2 = unpack(f,"<3f", 12)
                p3 = unpack(f,"<3f", 12)
                b = unpack(f,"<h", 2)

                normals.append(n)
                l = len(points)
                points.append(p1)
                points.append(p2)
                points.append(p3)
                triangles.append((l, l+1, l+2))
                #bytecount.append(b[0])


            def read_length(f):
                length = struct.unpack("@i", f.read(4))
                return length[0]

            def read_header(f):
                f.seek(f.tell()+80)


            read_header(f)
            l = read_length(f)

            try:
                while True:
                   read_triangle(f)
            #except Exception, e:
                #print "Exception",e[0]

            #write_as_ascii(outfilename)
            data=[points,triangles]


        jsdata=json.dumps(data)
        renderer_dict = dict(name=name,data=jsdata)

        path=shortuuid.uuid()
        html_string = render('tutorial:templates/view.pt', renderer_dict, request=request)
        s3=boto.connect_s3(aws_access_key_id = 'AKIAIJB6L7Q', aws_secret_access_key = 'sId01dYCMhl0wX' )
        bucket=s3.get_bucket('cubes.supercuber.com')
        k=Key(bucket)
        k.key='%(path)s' % {'path':path}
        k.set_contents_from_string(html_string, headers={'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
        k.set_acl('public-read')

        return HTTPFound(location="http://cubes.supercuber.com/%(path)s" % {'path':path})

    return {}
```

as you can see, the code checks whether an uploaded stl file is ascii (if is starts with the word "solid") or binary. If its ascii, everything works fine and the data variable gets filled with the vertices and ordering. However, if it doesn't start with solid and is a binary stl file the data variable never gets filled. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You read the first 5 bytes to check for the filetype, but never reset the file position to the beginning.

Add a call to `.seek(0)`:

```
f=input_file
f.seek(0)
```

You can always seek relatively without a call to `f.tell()`:

```
f.seek(80, 1)  # relative seek, you can use `os.SEEK_CUR` as well.
```

Comment: good call. I made that change and now it complains of a syntax error on the line that assigns data=[points,triangles]. Does this mean that they are still not getting filled?

Comment: If you get a SyntaxError you made a mistake somewhere; check the preceding lines and make sure all your parenthesis, brackets and braces are properly balanced (every {, [ and ( must be followed by a matching ), ] or }).

Comment: @BigBoy1337: I've also been ignoring your `try:` block before the `data=[points,triangles]` line; you cannot just comment out the except block, the `try:` block on it's own is a syntax error too. I presumed that that was an error in your post here only, but if that is your literal code it won't work.